# How can I change the redirection only for admin? by using devise and ActiveAdmin on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, device

I am currently working on the project using rails.
And I want to change the redirection when sign_out, but on my site every sign_out redirect to the same page with the code below.
I want to know how to make it difference.

please kindly tell me.
Thank you.

those are the code I found and used to redirect.

on application.controller

```
  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    if resource_or_scope == :user      ←this works
      new_user_session_path
    elsif resource_or_scope == :admin   ←this doesn't work.
      new_admin_session_path
    else
      user_root_path
    end
  end
```

Comment: What is your devise model look like? I guess both user & admin are on User model?

Comment: What is `resource_or_scope` at that point, i.e. after signing out as an admin?

Comment: Thank you so much for asking me.
Thanks to your comments, I realized that I have to know which model device is used for, and I found Staff model, so I changed it like below.
and I solved it. Thank you.

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    if resource_or_scope == :user    
      user_root_path
    elsif resource_or_scope == :staff   ←this doesn't work.
      admin_root_path
    end
  end

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments from kind people, I realized that I have to know which model device is used for, and I found Staff model, so I changed it like below.
and I solved it. Thank you.

```
  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    if resource_or_scope == :user    
      user_root_path
    elsif resource_or_scope == :staff   ←this doesn't work.
      admin_root_path
    end
  end
```